# Plot inequality in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I plot an inequality in 3D with matplotlib and numpy?

As an example:

```
[x > 0, x < 1],
[y > 1/4, y < (2*x - 1)]
[z > 1/3, z < (x + y - 1)]
```

Is this possible in matplotlib?

Would really appreciate the help!

Edit:
It would be ideal if it could be a surface plot

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how well your example aligns with your actual problem, but if they are both linear problems, then this might work.

For your problem, you should be able to analyze the inequalities and figure out what the region should look like. From the x and y inequalities, we know that the region is bounded on the right by x = 1, the bottom by y = 0.25, and along a diagonal given by y = 2x - 1. The z values are all greater than 1/3 within this region, so we don't need to worry about how that will change things.

The 2x tells us that the y-line has a slope of 2. Since the other edges are vertical or horizontal, we can create a meshgrid of the rectangular region and use twice as many points in y than in x (because we will cut off that corner and want the points to land *on* the line). We can then find the triangulation of this region by connecting two corners in the meshgrid rectangular grid. Finally, we can mask out the extra points and plot it using [`plot_trisurface`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.plot_trisurf.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.plot_trisurf).

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import tri

plt.close("all")

def create_triangle_indices_from_meshgrid(n, m, orientation=1):
    """Returns the indices into the flattened meshgrid which will create 
    triangles for `matplotlib.tri.Trangulation`. Provides two triangle
    orientations. One may be better than the other depending on the specific
    case.
    
    Orientation 1:

    1 - 2
    | \ |
    3 - 4

    Orientation 2:

    1 - 2
    | / |
    3 - 4

    """
    indices = np.arange(n*m).reshape(n, m)
    p1 = indices[1:, :-1].flatten()
    p2 = indices[:-1, :-1].flatten()
    p3 = indices[:-1, 1:].flatten()
    p4 = indices[1:, 1:].flatten()

    if orientation == 1:
        triangles1 = np.stack((p1, p2, p3), axis=1)
        triangles2 = np.stack((p1, p3, p4), axis=1)
        triangles = np.vstack((triangles1, triangles2))
    elif orientation == 2:
        triangles1 = np.stack((p2, p3, p4), axis=1)
        triangles2 = np.stack((p1, p2, p4), axis=1)
        triangles = np.vstack((triangles1, triangles2))
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Orientation number {orientation} does not exist.")

    return triangles

# twice as many points in x than y to ensure that the points will land on the line
# when masking
x = np.linspace(0.625, 1, 50)
y = np.linspace(0.25, 1, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = X + Y - 1

triangle_indices = create_triangle_indices_from_meshgrid(x.size, y.size, 2)
triangles = tri.Triangulation(X.flat, Y.flat, triangles=triangle_indices)
X_triangles = X.flatten()[triangle_indices]
Y_triangles = Y.flatten()[triangle_indices]

cond = (Y_triangles - 2*X_triangles > -1).any(1)
triangles.mask = cond

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection":"3d"})
ax.plot_trisurf(triangles, Z.flat)
ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax.set_ylabel("y")
ax.set_zlabel("z")
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's possible with `matplotlib` for example, using a scatter plot

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# The inequalities
def region_x(x):
    return (x > 0) & (x < 1)

def region_y(x, y):
    return (y > 1/4) & (y < (2*x - 1))

def region_z(x, y, z):
    return (z > 1/3) & (z < (x + y - 1))

# Creating a grid of points
x = np.linspace(-0.5, 1.5, 100)
y = np.linspace(-0.5, 1.5, 100)
z = np.linspace(-0.5, 1.5, 100)

X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(x, y, z)

# Applying the inequalities
mask = region_x(X) & region_y(X, Y) & region_z(X, Y, Z)

# Plotting
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Using the scatter plot
ax.scatter(X[mask], Y[mask], Z[mask], color='blue', s=1, alpha=0.5)

# Set labels and show the plot
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_title('3D Region Defined by Inequalities')

plt.show()
```

**Note**: [PyVista](https://github.com/pyvista/pyvista) and [Mayavi](https://github.com/enthought/mayavi) could be more suitable for this task.

Comment: the surface plot wouldn't be much different, I would have implemented it as a surface plot if you indicated such preference in the question ...

Comment: that's a difference yup, one would define the lower and upper boundaries